# Can't install wine32 and libwine:i386 on my ubuntu 20.04 computer

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit, wine

I would like to install wine32 on my ubuntu 20.04 but it's impossible.

If I run `sudo apt-get install wine32`, I've :

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 wine32:i386 : Dépend: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) mais ne sera pas installé
```

I run `sudo apt-get install libwine:i386` and :

```bash
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 libwine:i386 : Dépend: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) mais ne sera pas installé
                Dépend: libglib2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.12.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                Dépend: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) mais ne sera pas installé
                Dépend: libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.0.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                Dépend: libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 (>= 1.4.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                Dépend: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) mais ne sera pas installé
                Recommande: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.24) mais ne sera pas installé
                Recommande: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.25) mais ne sera pas installé
                Recommande: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 mais ne sera pas installé
```

I also checked in my ubuntu softwares updates if important and recommended updates are enabled :

[image]
[image]

And I think it's okay no?

I tried this :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

And a new time the first commands, but no changes.
I don't know what can I do anymore

My sources.list : https://pastebin.com/8dBR0mR4

EDIT :

I tried `apt policy libc6:{amd64,i386}` :

```bash
libc6:
  Installé : 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Candidat : 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
 Table de version :
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.7 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
libc6:i386:
  Installé : 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
  Candidat : 2.31-0ubuntu9.9
 Table de version :
 *** 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.31-0ubuntu9.7 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     2.31-0ubuntu9 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

I tried the following command : `sudo apt install libc6/stable`

```bash
E: La version « stable » de « libc6 » est introuvable
```

And `sudo apt install libc6` :

```bash
libc6 est déjà la version la plus récente (2.31-0ubuntu9.9).
libc6 passé en « installé manuellement ».
Les paquets suivants ont été installés automatiquement et ne sont plus nécessaires :
  linux-headers-5.13.0-48-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-48 linux-image-5.13.0-48-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-48-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-48-generic linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.13.0-48-generic linux-objects-nvidia-470-5.13.0-48-generic
  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.13.0-48-generic
Veuillez utiliser « sudo apt autoremove » pour les supprimer.
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
```

Comment: how do your /etc/apt/sources.list looks like?

Comment: check this maybe it helps https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590215/unable-to-install-wine32-on-debian

Comment: Hello, this is my source.list : https://pastebin.com/8dBR0mR4

Comment: Hello @BlockchainOffice I followed the instructions from your link, but no changes. I edited my first post with results

Comment: maybe this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1282029/cant-install-wine32-on-ubuntu-20-04 it's a problem with the architecture

Comment: I tried the solutions in your link but always the same thing :'(